# PHP - Отображение русских символов

Tags: php

Если вопрос уже задавался, прошу прощения, не нашел.К php-файлу посылается запрос с русскими символами, вот он к примеру:

```
    {'message': 'привет'}
```

На сервере вижу это

```
    {'message': 'u043f\u0440\u0438\u0432\u0435\u0442'}
```

Как превратить это в 'привет'?

Comment: Как посылается?

Comment: `json_decode()` и русские буквы становятся русскими

Comment: http://php.net/manual/ru/function.json-decode.php. **Эта функция работает только со строками в UTF-8 кодировке.**

Answer (score 5):

Проблемы в нестандартном JSON, видимо - сделанном руками. [По стандарту должны использоваться двойные кавычки.](http://www.json.org/) Заменим ординарные и проверим:

```
var_dump(json_decode(str_replace(
    "'",
    '"',
    "{'message': '\u043f\u0440\u0438\u0432\u0435\u0442'}"
)));
```

Выводит:

```
class stdClass#1 (1) {
  public $message =>
  string(12) "привет"
}
```

Правильным решением будет делать корректный JSON на передающей стороне, а не заменять кавычки на принимающей.

Answer (score 2):

Как посылается, через что? А вообще конечно задайте в заголовках UTF8, вот таким образом `header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8;");`.

Далее файл сделайте UTF-8 без BOM.

А ещё настройте локаль веб сервера.

Answer (score 2):

У вас проблемы с кодировкой. Можно поправить что бы присылало правильно(с нужными заголовками). Тогда `json_decode` справится. Смотрите ответ Евгения Иванова.

А можно конвертировать используя.
http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-convert-encoding.php

```
 mb_convert_encoding($utf16, 'UTF-8', 'UTF-16');
```

Если вы делаете кодирование строки в php.

То можно использоват флаг `JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE` что бы символы не конвертировались. http://php.net/manual/ru/function.json-encode.php